# Best approach for Java web service sending data to C# client

Tags: c#, jax-rs

Here’s our architecture:
JIRA webhook sends messages to a Java Jersey REST service when issues are assigned.

C# client application registers the username/host machine combo with the Java web service when a user logs into the machine

When the web service receives a message from JIRA, it finds the assignee username and sends the required data to the C# client app on the host machine(s) the user is logged into.

I’ve thought of a couple approaches to solve the web service to client message.

My first is opening a TCP port on the client and having the service send each message directly to it.  This is the most straight-forward approach but makes the client a little heavy in that it maintains the list of user assigned ticket data that they can then manipulate (acknowledge or remove).

The other is having the service maintain the data model and the client requests data periodically.  This makes the client simpler but then I’d have to implement a polling interval to grab data, and add some POST methods for acknowledging and removing data from the user’s list.

I was looking into different ways to have the client register a channel with the service, like ServiceStackEvents, but I can’t see a way to make that work with a C# client and Java service.  Something like that would be perfect.  A way for the service to send callbacks or event messages to a client based on a user filter.

If someone has some suggestions or knows of an API to help with this, please post a link so I can dig into it.  The POSTs are all working swimmingly, it’s just getting the data back to the clients that I’m struggling with the best approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Client polling is not a terrible solution.

But if you want a firewall and proxy friendly duplex protocol, check out WebSockets https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket.

Comment: Ah forgot about WebSockets! All of this (other than JIRA) is in the same enclave so firewalls aren’t a consideration.  I’ll play with both approaches.  Thanks for the input!